# How to covert this specific equation to matlab code

Tags: matlab, equation

How to represent this equation to matlab code

[image]

Comment: Why is this too broad? It seems to be a very precise question.  I know exactly what is being asked and how to answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so:

```
function y = sgn(x)
if x == 0
    y = 0;
else
    y = x / abs(x);
end
end
```